# Getting Error(We had some trouble connecting. Try again?) on submitting modal in slack

Tags: javascript, slack, hasura

When a user submits the modal, which I am using to collect information for a Slack bot, a lambda function is launched and an event is scheduled using hasura. I always receive this error when user is submitting the modal:

```
We had some trouble connecting. Try again?
```

`return {statusCode:200}` didn't solve the issue, and neither did the following:

```
let res = {
  body:"",
  statusCode:200,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  }
}
     
return res;
```

But none of the above worked. Any suggestions on what could be going wrong and how to proceed?

Comment: Can you show us the modal code? Maybe that would offer some insight into what is going wrong here.

Answer (score -1):

The problem may originate from the button you're using to submit the modal.
Showing the json structure could shine some light on that.

Comment: ```"type": "modal",
        "callback_id": "add",
        "title": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Settings",
            "emoji": true
        },
        "submit": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Submit",
            "emoji": true
        },
        "close": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Cancel",
            "emoji": true
        },
```

@Kacper Gruszczynski , This is the json of submit button which  is i am using.

Comment: This is not an answer and as such should not be posted as an answer. This should be a comment. With that said, it is true that the JSON is malformed though if what was provided is complete.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add these kind of content as comments (If not available for you wait for it). Answers should directly address a solution to the problem.